# Convert numeric values into binary (0/1)

Tags: r, dataframe, matrix, binary

I have a data frame  with counts of different kinds of fruits of different people. Like below

```
    apple  banana  orange
Tim     3       0       2
Tom     0       1       1
Bob     1       2       2
```

How can I change it into a binary matrix, i.e. if a person has at least one fruit, no matter how many he has, then the I record 1, if not, record 0. Like below

```
    apple  banana  orange
Tim     1       0       1
Tom     0       1       1
Bob     1       1       1
```

Comment: Is your object a matrix or a data frame? If it's a data frame with all numeric information you can coerce it to a matrix with `as.matrix`.

Comment: It's a data frame with headers

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Here's your `data.frame`:

```
x <- structure(list(apple = c(3L, 0L, 1L), banana = 0:2, orange = c(2L, 
1L, 2L)), .Names = c("apple", "banana", "orange"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("Tim", 
"Tom", "Bob"))
```

And your matrix:

```
as.matrix((x > 0) + 0)
    apple banana orange
Tim     1      0      1
Tom     0      1      1
Bob     1      1      1
```

### Update

I had no idea that a quick pre-bedtime posting would generate [any](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14526429/turn-a-count-matrix-into-a-binary-existence-matrix/14526637#comment20256941_14526637) [discussion](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/7380500#7380500), but the discussions themselves are quite interesting, so I wanted to summarize here:

My instinct was to simply take the fact that underneath a `TRUE` and `FALSE` in R, are the numbers `1` and `0`. If you try (a not so good way) to check for equivalence, such as `1 == TRUE` or `0 == FALSE`, you'll get `TRUE`. My shortcut way (which turns out to take **more time** than the *correct*, or at least *more conceptually correct* way) was to just add `0` to my `TRUE`s and `FALSE`s, since I know that R would coerce the logical vectors to numeric.

The correct, or at least, more appropriate way, would be to convert the output using `as.numeric` (I think that's what @JoshO'Brien intended to write). BUT.... unfortunately, that removes the dimensional attributes of the input, so you need to re-convert the resulting vector to a matrix, which, as it turns out, is ***still*** faster than adding `0` as I did in my answer.

Having read the comments and criticisms, I thought I would add one more option---using `apply` to loop through the columns and use the `as.numeric` approach. That is *slower* than manually re-creating the matrix, but *slightly faster* than adding `0` to the logical comparison.

```
x <- data.frame(replicate(1e4,sample(0:1e3)))
library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(X1 = {
            x1 <- as.matrix((x > 0) + 0)
          },
          X2 = {
            x2 <- apply(x, 2, function(y) as.numeric(y > 0))
          },
          X3 = {
            x3 <- as.numeric(as.matrix(x) > 0)
            x3 <- matrix(x3, nrow = 1001)
          },
          X4 = {
            x4 <- ifelse(x > 0, 1, 0)
          },
          columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", 
                      "relative", "user.self"))
#   test replications elapsed relative user.self
# 1   X1          100 116.618    1.985   110.711
# 2   X2          100 105.026    1.788    94.070
# 3   X3          100  58.750    1.000    46.007
# 4   X4          100 382.410    6.509   311.567

all.equal(x1, x2, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(x1, x3, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
all.equal(x1, x4, check.attributes=FALSE)
# [1] TRUE
```

Thanks for the discussion y'all!

Comment: Why is this better than `ifelse` ? (not asking because I suggested that, just curious)

Comment: @ChinmayPatil -- For one thing, Ananda's solution runs 3-4 times faster than the `ifelse()` version.  (FWIW `as.logical(as.matrix(x) > 0)` is twice again as fast as **his** solution.) Here's the data.frame I used to run a few time trials: `x <- data.frame(replicate(1e4,sample(0:1e3)))`.

Comment: @JoshO'Brien thanks for reply. I also checked same thing. It indeed is the case. :)

Comment: @JoshO'Brien, thanks. You did mean *`as.numeric`* though, right? I'll be updating my answer soon.

Comment: @ChinmayPatil, I've updated my answer with some benchmarks and further reflection.

Comment: @AnandaMahto -- Yes. Good catch. Thanks for posting those benchmarks!

Comment: Hi @A5C1D2H2I1M1N2O1R2T1 I noted some timings on `as.numeric` vs `as.integer` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943167/replace-true-and-false-values-with-1-and-0#comment49924462_30943167). Perhaps worth mention in your nice post? In addition, difference in memory required. Cheers

Answer (score 6):

I usually use this approach:

```
df[df > 0] = 1
```

Answer (score 4):

use can use `ifelse`. It should work on both matrix as well as dataframe however, resultant value will be matrix

```
> df <- cbind(aaple = c(3, 0 , 1), banana = c(0, 1, 2), orange = c(2, 1, 2))
> df
     aaple banana orange
[1,]     3      0      2
[2,]     0      1      1
[3,]     1      2      2

> ifelse(df>0, 1, 0)
     aaple banana orange
[1,]     1      0      1
[2,]     0      1      1
[3,]     1      1      1
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use a comparison:

```
d = t(matrix(c(3,0,2,0,1,1,1,2,2), 3))
d > 0
t(matrix(as.numeric(d>0), ncol(d)))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
> pippo
  person apple banana orange
1    Tim     1      0      2
2    Tom     0      1      1
3    Bob     1      2      2
> cols <- c("apple", "banana", "orange")
> lapply(cols, function(x) {pippo[,x] <<- as.numeric(pippo[,x] >= 1)})
```