# Replace logical values (TRUE / FALSE) with numeric (1 / 0)

Tags: r, dataframe, type-conversion, data.table

I am exporting data from R with the command:

```
write.table(output,file = "data.raw", na "-9999", sep = "\t", row.names = FALSE, col.names = FALSE)
```

It exports my data correctly, but it exports all of the logical variables as `TRUE` and `FALSE`.

I need to read the data into another program that can only process numeric values. Is there an efficient way to convert `logical` columns to numeric 1s and 0s during the export? I have a large number of numeric variables, so I was hoping to automatically loop through all the variables in the data.table

Alternatively, my output object is a `data.table`. Is there an efficient way to convert all the logical variables in a `data.table` into numeric variables?

In case it is helpful, here is some code to generate a `data.table` with a logical variable in it (it is not a large number of logical variables, but enough to use on example code):

```
DT = data.table(cbind(1:100, rnorm(100) > 0)
DT[ , V3:= V2 == 1 ]
DT[ , V4:= V2 != 1 ]
```

Comment: You asked about efficiency, so: `as.integer` is maybe 3x faster than `as.numeric` (which all the answers below use). I tried: `x <- sample(c(TRUE,FALSE,NA),1e8,replace=TRUE); system.time("+"(x)); system.time(as.integer(x)); system.time(as.numeric(x))`

Comment: @Frank thanks, I was wondering why everyone was using `as.numeric`--I assumed `as.integer` would be faster because of the smaller storage requirements...

Comment: @MichaelChirico  You are right about the `as.integer`.  With `data.table`, if you are changing some values in that column with the `mean` or so, there will be a clash of 'class.  Otherwise, it would be easier with `value=dat[[j]]+0L)`

Comment: The shortest is `+A`.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

For a data.frame, you could convert all logical columns to numeric with:

```
# The data
set.seed(144)
dat <- data.frame(V1=1:100,V2=rnorm(100)>0)
dat$V3 <- dat$V2 == 1
head(dat)
#   V1    V2    V3
# 1  1 FALSE FALSE
# 2  2  TRUE  TRUE
# 3  3 FALSE FALSE
# 4  4 FALSE FALSE
# 5  5 FALSE FALSE
# 6  6  TRUE  TRUE

# Convert all to numeric
cols <- sapply(dat, is.logical)
dat[,cols] <- lapply(dat[,cols], as.numeric)
head(dat)
#   V1 V2 V3
# 1  1  0  0
# 2  2  1  1
# 3  3  0  0
# 4  4  0  0
# 5  5  0  0
# 6  6  1  1
```

In `data.table` syntax:

```
# Data
set.seed(144)
DT = data.table(cbind(1:100,rnorm(100)>0))
DT[,V3 := V2 == 1]
DT[,V4 := FALSE]
head(DT)
#    V1 V2    V3    V4
# 1:  1  0 FALSE FALSE
# 2:  2  1  TRUE FALSE
# 3:  3  0 FALSE FALSE
# 4:  4  0 FALSE FALSE
# 5:  5  0 FALSE FALSE
# 6:  6  1  TRUE FALSE

# Converting
(to.replace <- names(which(sapply(DT, is.logical))))
# [1] "V3" "V4"
for (var in to.replace) DT[, (var):= as.numeric(get(var))]
head(DT)
#    V1 V2 V3 V4
# 1:  1  0  0  0
# 2:  2  1  1  0
# 3:  3  0  0  0
# 4:  4  0  0  0
# 5:  5  0  0  0
# 6:  6  1  1  0
```

Answer (score 38):

Simplest way of doing this!

Multiply your matrix by 1

For example:

```
A <- matrix(c(TRUE,FALSE,TRUE,TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE,TRUE),ncol=4)
A

#       [,1] [,2]  [,3]  [,4]
# [1,]  TRUE TRUE  TRUE FALSE
# [2,] FALSE TRUE FALSE  TRUE

B <- 1*A
B
#      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
# [1,]    1    1    1    0
# [2,]    0    1    0    1
```

(You could also add zero: `B <- 0 + A`)

Comment: Not only simplest, but also the fastest.

Answer (score 11):

What about just a:

```
dat <- data.frame(le = letters[1:10], lo = rep(c(TRUE, FALSE), 5))
dat
   le    lo
1   a  TRUE
2   b FALSE
3   c  TRUE
4   d FALSE
5   e  TRUE
6   f FALSE
7   g  TRUE
8   h FALSE
9   i  TRUE
10  j FALSE
dat$lo <- as.numeric(dat$lo)
dat
   le lo
1   a  1
2   b  0
3   c  1
4   d  0
5   e  1
6   f  0
7   g  1
8   h  0
9   i  1
10  j  0
```

or another approach could be with `dplyr` in order to retain the previous column if the case (no one knows) your data will be imported in R.

```
library(dplyr)
dat <- dat %>% mutate(lon = as.numeric(lo))
dat
Source: local data frame [10 x 3]

   le    lo lon
1   a  TRUE   1
2   b FALSE   0
3   c  TRUE   1
4   d FALSE   0
5   e  TRUE   1
6   f FALSE   0
7   g  TRUE   1
8   h FALSE   0
9   i  TRUE   1
10  j FALSE   0
```

#### Edit: Loop

I do not know if my code here is performing but it checks all column and change to numerical only those that are logical. Of course if your `TRUE` and `FALSE` are not logical but character strings (which might be remotely) my code won't work.

```
for(i in 1:ncol(dat)){

    if(is.logical(dat[, i]) == TRUE) dat[, i] <- as.numeric(dat[, i]) 

    }
```

Answer (score 11):

If there are multiple columns, you could use `set` (using @josilber's example)

```
library(data.table)
Cols <-  which(sapply(dat, is.logical))
setDT(dat)

for(j in Cols){
 set(dat, i=NULL, j=j, value= as.numeric(dat[[j]]))
}
```

Answer (score 10):

As [Ted Harding pointed out in the R-help mailing list](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2011-January/265121.html), one easy way to convert logical objects to numeric is to perform an arithmetic operation on them. Convenient ones would be `* 1` and `+ 0`, which will keep the TRUE/FALSE == 1/0 paradigm.

For your mock data (I've changed the code a bit to use regular R packages and to reduce size):

```
df    <- data.frame(cbind(1:10, rnorm(10) > 0))
df$X3 <- df$X2 == 1
df$X4 <- df$X2 != 1
```

The dataset you get has a mixture of numeric and boolean variables:

```
   X1 X2    X3    X4
1   1  0 FALSE  TRUE
2   2  0 FALSE  TRUE
3   3  1  TRUE FALSE
4   4  1  TRUE FALSE
5   5  1  TRUE FALSE
6   6  0 FALSE  TRUE
7   7  0 FALSE  TRUE
8   8  1  TRUE FALSE
9   9  0 FALSE  TRUE
10 10  1  TRUE FALSE
```

Now let

```
df2 <- 1 * df
```

(If your dataset contains character or factor variables, you will need to apply this operation to a subset of `df` filtering out those variables)

`df2` is equal to

```
   X1 X2 X3 X4
1   1  0  0  1
2   2  0  0  1
3   3  1  1  0
4   4  1  1  0
5   5  1  1  0
6   6  0  0  1
7   7  0  0  1
8   8  1  1  0
9   9  0  0  1
10 10  1  1  0
```

Which is 100% numeric, as `str(df2)` will show you.

Now you can safely export `df2` to your other program.

Answer (score 6):

One line solution

Using the following code we take all the logical columns and make them numeric.

```
library(magrittr)
dat %<>% mutate_if(is.logical,as.numeric)
```

Comment: also `mutate(across(where(is.logical), as.numeric))`

Answer (score 3):

The same as @saebod but with usual pipe.

```
library(dplyr)  

dat <- dat %>% 
  mutate_if(is.logical, as.numeric)
```