# R converted numbers to TRUE when importing Excel file

Tags: r

I just imported an Excel spreadsheet with 12 variables (columns) into R. Most of them are factors, but 4 of them are numeric.

The values of 2 out of those 4 numeric variables (`SES` and `Ed`) have been automatically converted to `TRUE` by R (instead of the original numbers in my spreadsheet).

This is what those numeric variables look like in the Excel file:

```
SES   Ed
3     4
9     6
5     4
...
```

And this is what they look like in R:

```
SES    Ed
TRUE   TRUE
TRUE   TRUE
TRUE   TRUE  
...
```

I'm not sure why R did this and why this happened only to 2 of the variables (the rest are still displaying the right values). I double-checked the Excel file and everything looks good there.

This is the code I used to import the file, in case it's helpful:

```
my_data = readxl::read_xlsx("my_data.xlsx")
```

Also if it helps, I realized that for these two variables, there were some missing values in the original Excel file (`NA`), something that did not occur with the other numeric variables, where every row has a value, so the issue might have originated because of this.

Could anyone say why this might have happened and how I can solve it?

Comment: See this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30943167/replace-logical-values-true-false-with-numeric-1-0

Comment: @mehmo I don't want to convert these logical values to 0's and 1's, but to the original values I had in my Excel file

Comment: I don't think converting TRUE/FALSE to 1/0 is what OP is looking for

Comment: Are there any wacky values in those columns of the spreadsheet? A spreadsheet column with all integer values should be read by read_xlsx correctly. Do cells in those columns have even one text value, date, etc?

Comment: Change missing value into 0 and import your excel file again

Comment: Use `col_types =` argument within `readxl::read_xlsx` to explicitly declare data type coming from Excel.

Comment: I tried replacing the `NA` by `0` and it worked! I didn't know R had trouble recognizing variables with several `NA` values in them. Thanks!

Comment: @aprendiz There are three logical states: true (`TRUE`), false (`FALSE`), and unknown (`NA`). Now `NA` also means "missing" when seen within (say) a character vector.  However, in my experience, R converts data into its simplest form: `logical` <`integer` < `numeric` < ... < `character` < `factor` < ... and so forth.  You'll notice that every `logical` {`TRUE`, `FALSE`, `NA`} can be represented as (say) an `integer` {`1`, `0`, `NA`} or a `character` {`"TRUE"`, `"FALSE"`, `NA`}; but not every `character` {`NA`, `"a"`, `"b"`, `"c"`, ..., `"ab"`, `"ac"`, ...} can be represented as a `character`.

Comment: @aprendiz However, every `integer` or `numeric` **can** be interpreted as a `logical`: any **nonzero** number means `TRUE`, while `0` means `FALSE`, and the numeric `NA` becomes a `logical` `NA`. In your case, the presence of `NA`s — which are primarily `logical` — made R interpret those two columns as `logical`, and once R had decided the columns were `logical`, it converted all those nonzero numbers to `TRUE`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by importing as a .csv rather than .xlsx