# multiple hot encoding in R dplyr?

Tags: r, dplyr, one-hot-encoding

In a situation where each observation may have up to 4 categories entered in a single cell (poor data entry i guess), how can i one-hot encode this in R? (Maybe the terminology should be multiple hot encoding but i'm not sure). Note that most of the observations have just one category, but some have 2, some 3 and some 4. Overall, the variable of interest has 7 distinct categories. This is what i did.
First i separated the column into four columns and separated the categories, one in each column.
Then i used the mutate and spread function in dplyr but i could only spread the first category ('firstcrop') for one-hot encoding purposes.

I created this dataframe to demonstrate my problem

```
library(dplyr)
bf <- data.frame(crops = c(1,3,345,9562))
bf <- separate(bf, crops, into = c('empty','firstcrop','secondcrop','thirdcrop','fourthcrop'), sep = "", extra = "merge")
bf <- select(bf, -(empty))
```

This code above successfully separates the categories into four separate columns. Next i do this to encode them into 1's and 0's. This worked only for the first crop.

```
cf<- bf%>%mutate(value = 1) %>% spread(firstcrop, value, fill = 0)
```

But i need to get a result like this where each observation could have multiple 1's.

| '1' | '2' | '3' | '4' | '5' | '6' | '9' |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 0 | 1 | 0 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 1 |

How do i go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a potential tidyverse solution:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
bf <- data.frame(crops = c(1,3,345,9562))
bf %>%
  separate(crops, into = c('empty',
                           'firstcrop',
                           'secondcrop',
                           'thirdcrop',
                           'fourthcrop'),
           sep = "", extra = "merge") %>%
  select(-(empty))  %>%
  mutate(row = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(-row) %>%
  na.omit() %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = value,
              values_from = name) %>%
  select(-row) %>%
  mutate(across(everything(), ~+!is.na(.x))) %>%
  select(order(colnames(.)))
#> Warning: Expected 5 pieces. Missing pieces filled with `NA` in 3 rows [1, 2, 3].
#> # A tibble: 4 × 7
#>     `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `6`   `9`
#>   <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int> <int>
#> 1     1     0     0     0     0     0     0
#> 2     0     0     1     0     0     0     0
#> 3     0     0     1     1     1     0     0
#> 4     0     1     0     0     1     1     1
```

<sup>Created on 2022-03-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Really helpful. However, I would need further clarification from you. for example, 
1. why do you pivot_longer and then pivot_wider
2. what this expression mean in the mutate function +!is.na(.x)? Is it this expression that gives us zero's and one's?

Comment: And one more issue, i copied and pasted your codes but i have this error message: "Error in n(), must be used inside dplyr verbs". I tried troubleshooting this and i made sure my plyr package was loaded first before dplyr package and then tidyr but it is still giving same error message. I am using version 4.1.2 of R. Thank you

Comment: You're welcome. The `pivot_longer()` is used to remove some of the NAs, and the `pivot_wider()` command is to set the column names as values ('1', '2' ... '9'). You are correct that `+!is.na(.x)` is what gives you 1's and 0s. Basically, the `!is.na(.x)` returns a logical statement - either 'value in column is not NA' is TRUE or FALSE - and the `+` converts the TRUE/FALSE to numeric. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/42785723/12957340 for further examples. As for your error, there is no `n()` in my code so please edit your question to include more details and I will help you troubleshoot

Answer (score 1):

Here’s a `data.table` solution in case anyone is interested:

```r
library(data.table)
bf <- data.table(crops = c(1, 3, 345, 9562))

bf[, crops := strsplit(as.character(crops), "")]
cols <- sort(unique(unlist(bf$crops)))
bf[, (cols) := lapply(cols, \(col) sapply(crops, \(row) col %in% row))]
bf
```

```
##      crops     1     2     3     4     5     6     9
## 1:       1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 2:       3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 3:   3,4,5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## 4: 9,5,6,2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

And a Base R solution:

```r
bf <- data.frame(crops = c(1, 3, 345, 9562))
bf$crops <- strsplit(as.character(bf$crops), "")
cols <- sort(unique(unlist(bf$crops)))
for (col in cols) {
    bf[[col]] <- sapply(bf$crops, \(row) col %in% row)
}
bf
```

```
##        crops     1     2     3     4     5     6     9
## 1          1  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 2          3 FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
## 3    3, 4, 5 FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
## 4 9, 5, 6, 2 FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, it is really insightful. But i don't understand the  \ (row) in the sapply function. Please could you clarify?

Comment: `\(row)` is the same as `function(row)`. It just creates a temporary function that `sapply` will apply to every element of `bf$crops`