# Converting Multiple choice response to one-hot encoding

Tags: r, excel, dplyr

I have an excel file that has data containing questions having multiple choice response. For example this question, has 15 multiple choice options. I'd like to transpose the responses, which are in this [format](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1hDSr3yC_6hy5vEUToHUynUqKYWpotwZ_5jIL3Nf3PAI/edit?usp=sharing) to adopt a **one-hot encoding format**. This in the end will make it easier for me to perform analysis.

*The question*

**Best Aspect to Distance learning?**

1. Flexibility
2. Accessibility
3. Timeframe
4. Quality of modules
5. Learning resources
6. Pre-course
7. Quality of residentials
8. Number of Residentials
9. Quality of Tutorials
10. Frequency of Tutorials
11. Quality of Mentoring support
12. Frequency of Mentoring support
13. The programme's inclusive approach that benefits learners of all genders
14. The programme's impact on personal confidence and self-improvement
15. The programme’s impact on improved teaching skills

How do I do this in R? I'm not good in excel but a 2nd excel alternative will help.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not the place to ask others to write your code *for you*, though the community is very willing to help you solve specific problems you encounter whilst writing it *for yourself*. What have you tried so far and why didn't it work?

Comment: I don't have a starting point. I know how to analyse one-hot encoded questions. 
If there's no solution. I can do it manually. I was thinking there's a short cut to this

Comment: create a smaller version, with the input, and your desired output. Decide if you want an excel answer or an R answer

Comment: You can start by doing some research on the problem. For example, what happened when you tried to apply the solution suggested in one of the [Related Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71462428/multiple-hot-encoding-in-r-dplyr?rq=2) listed below?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems like, based on one-hot encoding tables I've seen online, you're wanting something like this:

```
library(tidyverse)

df <- read_csv("/Users/mark/Downloads/Best Aspect to Distance learning - Sheet1.csv")
df |> 
  mutate(row = row_number(),
         `Best Aspect to Distance learning` = str_split(`Best Aspect to Distance learning`, ", |,| and ")) |> 
         unnest(`Best Aspect to Distance learning`) |> 
         pivot_wider(names_from = `Best Aspect to Distance learning`, values_from = `Best Aspect to Distance learning`, values_fn = ~ 1, values_fill = 0)
```

Output:

```
# A tibble: 13 × 19
     row   `1`   `2`   `3`   `4`   `5`   `7`   `8`   `9` others  `10`  `15`
   <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
 1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      1     0     0
 2     2     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1      0     0     0
 3     3     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0      0     0     0
 4     4     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     1      0     1     1
 5     5     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     1      0     0     0
 6     6     1     1     1     1     1     0     1     0      0     0     0
 7     7     1     1     0     0     0     1     1     0      0     0     0
 8     8     1     1     1     0     1     0     0     0      0     0     1
 9     9     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0      0     0     0
10    10     0     1     0     1     0     1     0     0      0     0     0
11    11     0     1     1     0     0     0     1     0      0     0     0
12    12     1     1     0     1     1     1     0     0      0     0     0
13    13     0     1     1     1     0     1     0     1      0     0     0
# ℹ 7 more variables: `11` <dbl>, `35` <dbl>, `13` <dbl>, `16` <dbl>,
#   `6` <dbl>, `12` <dbl>, `14` <dbl>
```

You might want to include columns for all numbers from the min to the max, even ones where every value will be zero, but you haven't mentioned that. Let me know if that's something you want. A desired output would be great.

Comment: Hi Mark, this is the desired output. 
However, I don't understand, what do you mean by ..."You might want to include columns for all numbers from the min to the max"...

If the proposed columns are 18, based on the count of multiple choice options, does it mean that min=0 and max=18? 

If so how do you edit the code? Thank you very much

Comment: What I mean to say is, suppose the first (and only) row was "1, 2, 5". Would you want it to include all number columns, i.e.  1 2 3 4 5, or just the ones which appear in the row

Comment: Only the ones that appear in the row. Does this code work this way, or will you have to edit. Its the preferred approach I'll use.

Comment: yes, that's what I've already done @andy

Comment: Sorry mark, I'd like to include all the numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `fastDummies` package:

```
# # If necessary, install the package
# install.packages("fastDummies")
 
# Load the library
library(fastDummies)
 
# Using your 'Best Aspect to Distance learning' dataset
data <- name_of_your_dataset
 
# Create dummy variables
data <- dummy_cols(data, 
                   select_columns = "Best Aspect to Distance learning")
 
# Verify
print(data)
```

Comment: how does this answer the question sorry?

Comment: I ask because I tried running it in the example and it doesn't produce the desired output