# How to have data.table directly return values of 1/0 instead of TRUE/FALSE?

Tags: r, data.table

I'm wondering if there's a direct way for data.table in R to return values of 1/0, instead of TRUE/FALSE/NA, when testing for a condition. In the below MWE code, data.table does a correct job of returning TRUE in the "firstX" column when encountering the first value of X in the "stX" column for a given ID group. How can I tune data.table so it instead returns 1/0, a 1 if the condition is TRUE and otherwise return 0? I can convert those TRUE, FALSE, NA values in the "firstX" column to 1/0 using base R or dplyr but I wonder if data.table has a more direct approach. My quest is shown in this image:

[image]

Code:

```
library(data.table)

df1 <- data.frame(
  ID=c(rep(1,3),rep(2,3),rep(3,4)),
  Mo = c(seq(1:3),seq(1:3),seq(1:4)),
  stX= c("NA","X","X","NA","NA","NA","NA","X","NA","NA")
  )
df2 <- df1
df2 <- setDT(df2)[, firstX := .I == .I[stX == 'X'][1],ID]
```

Comment: Seems it is answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30943225/9076343

Comment: Either `firstX := as.integer(.I == .I[stX == 'X'][1])` or the shortly shorter trick `firstX := +(.I == .I[stX == 'X'][1])`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Comments above work except for ID = 2 in my example, where there is not an X event in the "stX" column, so the "firstX" column comes back with NA mfor this ID. However, ID = 1 and 3 are correctly calculated (TRUE represented as 1 and FALSE as 0) since there are X events in the "stX" column for these ID's. So I threw in a little base R to convert all lingering NA's to 0's:

```
df2 <- setDT(df2)[, firstX := +(.I == .I[stX == 'X'][1]),ID] %>% replace(is.na(.), 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this:

```
setDT(df1)[, firstX:=+((1:.N) == min(which(stX=="X"))), ID]
```

Output:

```
       ID    Mo    stX firstX
    <num> <int> <char>  <int>
 1:     1     1     NA      0
 2:     1     2      X      1
 3:     1     3      X      0
 4:     2     1     NA      0
 5:     2     2     NA      0
 6:     2     3     NA      0
 7:     3     1     NA      0
 8:     3     2      X      1
 9:     3     3     NA      0
10:     3     4     NA      0
```

Comment: Hi there, your solution works fine but with the following warning message "Warning message: In min(which(stX == "X")) : no non-missing arguments to min; returning Inf"

Comment: Yes that is correct. It can be ignored, or explicitly suppressed if you like